# How to conditionally call useEfect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, webhooks, use-effect

I need to call useEffect hook, but unless two conditions will be `true`

Something like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('PRINT SOMETHING ') 
}, [reduxState.age > 26 && reduxState.employee === true])
```

I know i could insert those conditions inside useEffect with `if`, and do whatever i want.
But the problem is that i have another tab with very similar useEffect.
And i need to somehow separete them.
In order to not call unwanted useEffect from another Tab.
Would it be possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "another tab"? Also, it might make sense to merge the `useEffect` logic into a single one, and split the inner logic using if/else gates and etc.

Comment: I simplified code as much as possible.
I have app with several pages.
And each page contains a few tabs.
When You select one tab You see one content on page.
And so on.
I could merge all logic in to one 'useEffect', but this stracture was  implemented before me on every page and tab. So i will have to modify about 12 pages

Answer (score 3):

React shallow compares the dependency array with previous values and if it changes it will run useEffect.

So in your example if you change reduxState.age from 27 to 28 the deps array is still true and useEffect is not triggered.

Correct way is to put the condition inside useEffect. You can have more conditions in one useEffect or you can write more useEffects.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (reduxState.age < 18 && reduxState.employee === true) 
    console.log('Employee younger than 18');
  if (reduxState.age > 26 && reduxState.employee === true) 
    console.log('Employee older than 26');
}, [reduxState.age, reduxState.employee])
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (reduxState.age < 18 && reduxState.employee === true) 
    console.log('Employee younger than 18');
}, [reduxState.age, reduxState.employee])

useEffect(() => {
  if (reduxState.age > 26 && reduxState.employee === true) 
    console.log('Employee older than 26');
}, [reduxState.age, reduxState.employee])
```

This is common usage.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I was also thinking about this logic.
But i worry about having a lot of unwanted calls to second useEffect

Comment: It is by design and it is not a performance issue. ;)

Comment: And if you use same code on 12 pages you can extract the code to custom hook.